# Setting AppVeyor's C++ Language Standard

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, appveyor

I'm trying to use AppVeyor to build a [Visual Studio 2017 project](https://github.com/SilensAngelusNex/FireEmblem) that uses some c++17 features. I have the project's language standard set to *c++latest*, so it compiles fine in my local Visual Studio, but AppVeyor isn't able to successfully build it. I get a bunch of errors like this:

> error C7525: inline variables require at least '/std:c++17'

[Here's the AppVeyor page](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/SilensAngelusNex/fireemblem) and here's the contents of my YAML file.

```
version: 1.0.{build}
image: Visual Studio 2017 Preview

init:
- ps: >-
    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include"

    svn checkout https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/trunk/include/gsl

    cd C:\projects\fireemblem
environment:
  matrix:
   - additional_flags: "/std:c++latest"

before_build:
  - set CXXFLAGS=%additional_flags%

build:
  verbosity: normal
```

Comment: What would you recommend using instead?

Comment: Teamcity of course.

Comment: @WestonCarvalho: seems that this is Visual Studio only setting. It looks like for msbuild-based CI people are using `additional_flags` environment variable. Please see results for `appveyor.yml /std:c++latest` search on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=appveyor.yml+%2Fstd%3Ac%2B%2Blatest&type=Code

Comment: Somehow my claim that appveyor is junk got deleted. I repeat it is trash, avoid it. Use Jenkins if you don't like Teamcity, just don't use appveyor.

Comment: @WestonCarvalho also note that `- set CXXFLAGS=%additional_flags%` sometime before build is needed.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Both of those require me to set up my own build server, correct? I don't have a computer I can leave on all the time to do builds, so the fact that AppVeyor builds on its own cloud is a strong mark in it's favor, even if it's more trouble in other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `<LanguageStandard>stdcpplatest</LanguageStandard>` is set for *each* of the configurations in your project file instead of just the win32 Debug configuration.